# Stop Spyder from importing modules like `numpy`, `pandas`, etc

Tags: python, spyder

When I start Spyder, it automatically imports `pandas` and `numpy`.  Is it possible to have Spyder ignore these modules?

I see these are imported in multiple Spyderlib files.  For example, `pandas` gets imported in `spyderlib/widgets/importwizard.py`, `spyderlib/baseconfig.py`, etc.

(I'm trying to debug something in `pandas` and I'd like to import it for the first time in a debugging session in Spyder)

Comment: It needs to import your packages to provide auto-completion.  Isn't that what you'd want from an IDE?  What problem are you trying to solve here?

Comment: @JohnZwinck, thanks, I've updated the question to explain my motivation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(*Spyder dev here*) This is not possible. If Pandas is installed on the same Python installation where Spyder is, then Spyder will import Pandas to: a) report to its users the minimal version needed to view DataFrames in the Variable Explorer and b) import csv files as DataFrames.

The only solution I can suggest you is this:

1. Create a new virtualenv or conda environment
2. Install there Spyder and its dependencies, but not Pandas. Spyder dependencies can be checked under the menu `Help > Optional dependencies`
3. Start your virtualenv/conda env Spyder
4. Go to

   `Tools > Preferences > Console > Advanced Settings > Python executable`

   select the option `Use the following Python interpreter` and write (or select) there the path to the interpreter where you have Pandas installed (e.g. `/usr/bin/python`)
5. Start a new Python/IPython console and import pandas there.

Answer (score 0):

Might be a little late, but I ran into this issue when I updated Spyder to 5.3.3 where it was automatically loading numpy and matplotlib. The solution that worked for me:

1. Navigate to `Tools > Preferences > IPython console > Graphics`
2. Uncheck "Automatically load Pylab and NumPy modules"
3. Start a new IPython console.

Hope this helps!